# Install lxml into virtualenv

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, lxml

I am attempting to install the latest lxml module in a virtualenv with Python3.4 on Windows 7. As a long time Linux user, this process should be simple, but, of course, it's not. I'm trying to install the latest lxml, and there is currently no package that works with Python3.4+ Consequently, I acquired libxml2 and libxslt, but I cannot seem to get anything to recognize them. Can anyone point me in the right direction of linking everything together.

I've tired pretty much everything from http://lxml.de/build.html and all the variants I can think of. Any help would be much appreciated.

Error logs below:

```
Building lxml version 3.4.1.
Building with Cython 0.21.1.
ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

Using build configuration of libxslt
missing cimport in module 'lxml.includes': src\lxml\lxml.etree.pyx
missing cimport in module 'lxml.includes.tree': src\lxml\lxml.etree.pyx
missing cimport in module 'lxml.python': src\lxml\lxml.etree.pyx
missing cimport in module 'lxml': src\lxml\lxml.etree.pyx
missing cimport in module 'lxml.includes': src\lxml\lxml.objectify.pyx
missing cimport in module 'lxml.includes.etreepublic': src\lxml\lxml.objectify.pyx
missing cimport in module 'lxml.includes.tree': src\lxml\lxml.objectify.pyx
missing cimport in module 'lxml': src\lxml\lxml.objectify.pyx
C:\Python34\Lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running build
running build_py
copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win32-3.4\lxml\includes
running build_ext
building 'lxml.etree' extension
C:\minGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Users\username\Desktop\angelScripts\draft\lxml-master\src\lxml\includes -IC:\Pyth
on34\include -IC:\Python34\include -c src\lxml\lxml.etree.c -o build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.o -w
In file included from src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:239:0:
C:\Users\username\Desktop\angelScripts\draft\lxml-master\src\lxml\includes/etree_defs.h:14:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlvers
ion.h: No such file or directory
 #include "libxml/xmlversion.h"
                               ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'C:\\minGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend downloading [`lxml`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) from Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows Repository. Select either `lxml‑3.4.1.win‑amd64‑py3.4.exe` or `lxml‑3.4.1.win32‑py3.4.exe`, depending on whether you're running a 64- or 32-bit Python installation, respectively. Don't run the installer, but instead unzip it. Move the contents of the resulting `PLATLIB` folder (an `lxml` directory, and an `lxml-3.4.1-py3.4.egg-info` directory) to the `site-packages` folder in your virtualenv, and you should be all set.

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded *lxml-3.4.4-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl* from [Christoph's Gohlke's Python page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and install it using

```
pip install lxml-3.4.4-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had this problem, and here's how I solved it:

First try to pip install it. Go to command prompt and type in
C:/Python34/Scripts/pip install lxml

If you still got an error, than go to [Christoph's Gohlke's Python page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml)

and then download the right lxml. Generally since I use python 3.4 and I have a windows, I download the lxml-3.4.4-cp34-none-win32.whl

Now that you have a whl file, go to the folder it is in. Click in the background (so nothing is selected), then leftshift + rightclick at the same time and click on open command window. Then type
C:/Python34/Scripts/pip install "NAME OF THE FILE YOU JUST DOWNLOADED.whl"

and press enter. This worked well for me, and after you type the quote you can also press tab and it should fill the right one for you.